# Error about Selenium version using Python's webbot

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webbot

I'm using Python 3.9 on macOS. I'm trying to start using webbot, but every time I try, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created 
exception: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562713 
(dd642283e958a93ebf6891600db055f1f1b4f3b2),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
```

I'm using macOS version 10.4 because I use 32 bit software. The part that really puzzles me is why is says `chromedriver=2.39.562713`. According to the pip, the driver's version is 103.0.5060.53. If I import `selenium` and try the command `help(selenium)`, towards the end of the output, I get:

```
VERSION
    4.3.0
```

Where does this lower version come from? I'm pretty sure that's why I have "missing or invalid capabilities." If I start selenium with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

It starts Chrome as expected. Obviously I'm missing something.

I used to start webbot with:

```
from webbot import Browser
driver = Browser()
```

But then, just to be sure, I changed it to:

```
from webbot import Browser
driver = Browser(True, None, '/usr/local/bin/')
```

'/usr/local/bin/' being the location of a chrome webdriver installed by brew that is explicitly version 103. No difference.

### Solution

The approved response was not the solution, but it led me to the solution.

My version of `webbot` is the latest, but it has a very different `__init__` method:

```
    def __init__(self, showWindow=True, proxy=None , downloadPath:str=None):
```

Upon further inspection, I saw that the `driverPath` attribute (that I had tried to use earlier) was completely gone by design. So I decided to print the value of the inner variable `driverpath` *inside* the `__init__` method. This returned the following:

```
project_root/virtualenvironment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webbot/drivers/chrome_mac
```

There was my guilty party! I renamed that executable and in its place put a symbolic link to the correct binary. That worked.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you did to resolve the problem? I have exactly the same issue here..thx!

Comment: "I renamed that executable and in its place put a symbolic link to the correct binary.":  do you rename chrome_mac to something else, and what's "correct binary"?

Comment: Not sure if this would help anyone anymore, but I had this problem on Windows 10 today, I just went to  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and downloaded the right driver for my version of chrome and replaced the version in `venv\Lib\site-packages\webbot\drivers` it's working on my computer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver = Browser(True, None, '/usr/local/bin/')
```

actually sets the `downloadPath`, not the `driverPath`. Use the parameter name explicitly

```
driver = Browser(driverPath='/usr/local/bin/')
```

From [webbot.py](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot/blob/333f51840cd5a1fcde0b014bd6ab401d51e62860/webbot/webbot.py#L41)

```
class Browser:
    def __init__(self, showWindow=True, proxy=None , downloadPath:str=None, driverPath:str=None, arguments=["--disable-dev-shm-usage","--no-sandbox"]):

        if driverPath is not None and isinstance(driverPath,str):
            driverPath = os.path.abspath(driverPath)
            if(not os.path.isdir(driverPath)):
                raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerror(errno.ENOENT), driverPath)

        if driverPath is None:
            driverfilename = ''
            if sys.platform == 'linux' or sys.platform == 'linux2':
                driverfilename = 'chrome_linux'
            elif sys.platform == 'win32':
                driverfilename = 'chrome_windows.exe'
            elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
                driverfilename = 'chrome_mac'
            driverPath = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'drivers{0}{1}'.format(os.path.sep, driverfilename))
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverPath, options=options)
```

If `driverPath` is `None` it will set to
`/{parent_folder_abs_path}/drivers/chrome_mac` or `/{parent_folder_abs_path}/drivers/`, I'm guessing you have an older `chromedriver` version there.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks! I looked carefully into how to set the options, though. I must have set it wrong anyway.